# How do I fix OSX Maps having the wrong location (Next Door)

Tags: macos, wifi, geolocation, maps

On OSX Maps, when I use my "Current Location" always resolves to the house next door.

This is easy enough to override, by never using my current location, but is there a way to make it know the real location of my Mac? Like reset Apples DB of where my Wifi is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if they'll fix this sort of problem, but you could try reporting it through the "Report a Problem..." feature under the Apple Maps application menu. Not sure if it fits any of the listed problems but you could try using the "My problem is not listed" option.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just realised that they have the pin for my property listed at the wrong spot as well, so I've reported a problem about that as well. Maybe their algorithms would have worked better if that was correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a way of doing this. Apple does use croud-sourced data obtained from iPhones though: get an iPhone and let it get its location. Using GPS the iPhone will obtain an actual location, and as it can scan for Wi-Fi the data can be combined.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yeah I've got a iPad and iPhone in the same house as well. But somehow its decided that I live in the house next door ... which is also empty, so I could just go squat there.